# Plural vs Singular when the number 1 is represented in integer vs decimal form

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers, irregular-plurals, inflections

If I have a noun of cardinality 1, I am taught that I use the singular form.

E.g. `I have 1 Apple`

---

If the value is still `1`, but represented as `1.0`, do I still use the singular form?

E.g. `I have 1.0 Apple`

It seems laymen would say `I have 1.0 Apples`; is this just a trick of the brain but not valid English, or is plural correct even though the value is still 1?

Comment: 'One **and** something' is plural, even if the something is nothing.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=1.0+plural